# Team Foundation Server: Deploying non-MSBuild compiled HTML and Javascript

Tags: deployment, tfs, tfsbuild

At work we are starting to write more apps which are specifically non-compiled HTML along with minified/de-CoffeeScripted Javascript libraries. The problem is that I cannot figure out a good way to make use of our current builds in such a way that we can continue to utilize the deployment aspects (our builds are to deploy their outputs to our web servers) while not using MSBuild to compile.

In short my question is..
We currently have builds which can deploy to our web servers. Without rewriting the deployment aspect, I would like to have builds which can deploy just flat files or possibly minify/de-CoffeeScript some javascript libraries. How should I go about making this happen?

Comment: Is creating a dummy project and adding the files to the project an option?

Comment: @sunil that can be done, but it seems to be a bit of a hack. I suppose I'd have to hack it in order to deploy non-microsoft files, but I'm hoping for something that seems more standard.